# How do I scale a value iteratively but still achieve a specific fraction of the original?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

This is pretty much a simple math problem but Im bad with math. Let's say Im doing something like:

```
let originalWidth = img.width;
let originalHeight = img.height;
for (let percent = 100; percent >= 10; percent -= 5) {
  let percentScale = percent / 100;
  let ctx = img.getContext("2d");
  ctx.scale(percentScale, percentScale);
  img.width = originalWidth * percentScale;
  img.height = originalHeight * percentScale;
  ....
```

In this example `ctx.scale(percentScale, percentScale);` is going to scale it a percentage of the resulting scale from the previous scaling iteration, when what I want is a percentage of the original, but I dont want to copy the original object and scale from there each time because scaling iteratively saves computation and performance is a factor here.

How can I alter my code to get the math right for this?

Comment: What do you mean percentage of the original? right now percentScale goes down by 5 each iteration, and this is no good? what is percentScale supposed to be?

Comment: Take a look at how tween engines do it and also check easing functions. Here are some examples: [Easings.net](https://easings.net/en) and [Easing Gist](https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cancel out the last applied scaling factor:

```
let originalWidth = img.width;
let originalHeight = img.height;
let lastScale = 1;
for (let percent = 100; percent >= 10; percent -= 5) {
   let percentScale = percent / 100;
   let adjustedScale = percentScale / lastScale;
   lastScale = percentScale;
   let ctx = img.getContext("2d");
   ctx.scale(adjustedScale, adjustedScale);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scale be a factor of *x* in *n* steps, each step should scale by `pow(x,1.0/n)`